# Associate an existing image with a post

Tags: images, attachments

I'm trying to associate an existing image from the media library with a post (It's a custom post type), If I use `wp_insert_attachment` I get a duplicate in the media library, so I'm getting the image `id` and using that as the `attach_id`.

```
$attach_id = intval( $file['id'] );
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
$result = wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
```

This doesn't work and the `$result` is false.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Can anybody enlighten me?

Comment: are you want to set featured image?

Comment: No, I want to associate a number of images with a post. like a gallery of images for that post, I'm using the built in media dialog to upload images but I need to associate existing images selected using the new media dialog. Thanks.

Comment: How are you planning to display the attachments to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify an existing media library image using [`wp_insert_attachment`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) by setting the `ID` key in the parameter array.

```
$attachment = array(
    'ID' => $existing_library_attachment_id,
    'post_parent' => $custom_post_id
);
wp_insert_attachment( $attachment );
```

This will update the attachment post with ID `$existing_library_attachment_id` to have a `post_parent` value of `$custom_post_id`.  However, the only thing this will affect is the permalink of the attachment post.  Unless you do something else to edit your custom post itself, you won't see any changes on that post.

Here are some things you can do to attach the image to your post:

1. To make the image the "featured image" of your post, use the [`set_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail) function:

   ```
   set_post_thumbnail( $custom_post_id, $existing_library_attachment_id );
   ```
2. To show the picture in the content area of your post, you need to edit the post_content of your post (with [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post), for example).  To add an individual image to your post, you can add an `<img>` tag (perhaps using the [`get_image_tag`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_image_tag) function).  If you want to add a gallery, use the [`[gallery]` shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode).

Comment: Hi, I'm not trying to set a featured image,I know how to do that. I want to set a number of images as attachments so there is an association with the post.

Comment: @Lee I've expanded my answer.

Comment: these days (4.7+) post_mime_type needs to be set for the update to work properly. Can also just use wpdb to add the post_parent

Comment: It should also be noted that these days wp_insert_attachment's third parameter is the parent field optionally expecting the ID of the post it will be attached to:
wp_insert_attachment( string|array $args, string $file = false, int $parent, bool $wp_error = false )

So ideally that will be called during the upload/save process with wp_handle_upload moving the image to the correct location and returning the full meta thus allowing wp_insert_attachment attaching it to the post.

Answer (score 3):

I have decided to post it as a separate post and not a comment because it will be lost.
I've tried Ben's solution but it modifies the attachment's other data fields.
I ended up using this.

```
            $attachment = array(
                'ID' => $att_id,
                'post_parent' => $custom_post_id,
            );

            $res = wp_update_post($attachment);
```

Comment: Add clean_attachment_cache($att_id) to clear the media library cache. Took me a while to figure out why it wasn't working. This was it!